# Do flowfields trigger onModify event ? NAV

Tags: events, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-nav

Do flowfields on a page triggers the on modify of a table ? As to what I have noticed, it doesn't ?

How can i trigger an any event(on validate, on modify) if a flowfield is changed on a page ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

You can’t. Flowfields are calculated on sql server side and fetched only when you do get/find/calcfields.

Comment: Agreed. However... FlowFields are calculated based on information in another table (as defined in their CalcFormula property). The outcome of the calculation may change in response to a. a change in that underlying table, or b. a change in a FlowFilter field. @Lam You may be able to solve your problem by responding those changes instead?